# Use helm in specific modes and not for other buffers in different mode

Tags: helm, lsp-mode, lsp

I recently started using lsp-java and one of the packages it suggests is helm.
The suggested changes to the .emacs file to do this is:

```
(use-package helm-lsp)
(use-package helm
    :config (helm-mode))
```

This obviously works to start helm mode.

This issue I have is if I open another buffer in another mode (say shell in shell-mode)
it continues to use helm which I really don't like.

I have tried adding the helm-lsp and helm mode initializing into a function which in turn is loaded via a java-mode-hook:

```
(defun init-lsp-java-stuff ()
       (interactive)
       ...
       (use-package helm-lsp)
       (use-package helm
           :config (helm-mode))
       ...
)
...

(add-hook 'java-mode-hook 'init-lsp-java-stuff)
```

This works if I never enter java mode, but still after entering java mode all my other buffers have helm loaded.

What I want is for helm to ONLY be loaded for java-mode buffers, and NOT be loaded for buffers in any other mode.

Comment: I think `helm-mode` is the culprit. You can use helm by itself, but "helm mode" [turns it on everywhere](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/wiki#helm-mode). You might try leaving in everything except the call to `(helm-mode)` and see if that helps. You might also need to configure helm-lsp with this define-key: https://github.com/emacs-lsp/helm-lsp#configuration

Answer (score 1):

Don't call helm-mode at all. Helm-mode does not introduce anything for `lsp-java` per se but IMO improves general emacs usability. You could use helm-lsp function without having helm-mode enabled.